# Why my application crash on device when changing the button text if i touch the device screen?

Tags: android, eclipse

I added to the activitiy java file:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Button p1_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    p1_button.setText("Some text");
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Once I add this:

```
Button p1_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
p1_button.setText("Some text");
```

The application crash when I touch the screen on my device.
If im removing this two lines when touching the screen on my device will not do anything but also will not crash.

This is the main xml file where the button is added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/videoview" 
    android:layout_width="720px"
    android:layout_height="480px"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/mybutton" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="REC"
    android:textSize="12dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I wanted to do that when I touch the screen on my device it will change the button text.
What should I do ?

Comment: Can you post the logcat?

Comment: have you tried as : `Button p1_button = (Button)Your_Current_Activity.this.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
p1_button.setText("Some text");`

Comment: Make sure you called first the `setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_layout);` in `onCreate()` of your `Activity`. It seems you're getting `NullPointerException`

Comment: Glenn I have already that in the top of the activity java file: setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K tried it not working.

Comment: Glenn how do I see or get the logcat log ? On my eclipse bottom I have a window tab of the logcat but all I see is some red line wich is gone after few seconds. How do I use the logcat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the button does not exist in this context you are trying to find it. Define the button as `static` in your class and find it in the `onCreate`

```
static Button p1_button;

...

protected void onCreate(...){
 ....
p1_button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
}
```

then use the `p1_button` variable in the `onTouchEvent`

**OR**

you can pass the activity in the `onTouchEvent` like

```
final Activity activity = this;
```

and then

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Button p1_button = (Button)activity.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    p1_button.setText("Some text");
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```